# Use Matlab FIS in Java application

Tags: java, matlab, jakarta-ee, web-applications, fuzzy-logic

I have a Matlab FIS using the GUI that accepts 3 integer/float inputs and produces an output. It is a basic credit profiler that determined your credit score based on income, debt balance e.t.c.

I have a Java web application (running on Tomcat 8.5 localhost) and want to implement a way where I can call a method that expect 4 parameters. In this method I want Java to call the Matlab FIS and supply the arguments passed to Matlab. The Integer output Matlab FIS produces would be returned to the method which in turn would return to the caller class.

I have extensively researched online but cannot find any related information.
Thanks

Comment: See [Selecting a MATLAB Application Deployment Strategy](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/selecting-a-matlab-application-deployment-strategy.html)

Comment: I have already reviews so many MathWorks documentation pages including this one. The AppBuilder to convert to Jar provided by Matlab only convert . files. As I used the gui i have a .fis file. This is the part I am struggling with. Either I convert to .m file (which i dont know how to do) or there is another way to directly use the fis